# java json string to url query string

Tags: java, json

Two days i spend to search efficent method to convert json string to url query string, for example
SRC:

```
"searchCriteria": {
    "filterGroups": [
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "field": "myfiled",
            "value": "myvalue",
            "conditionType": "eq"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "sortOrders": [
      {
        "field": "string",
        "direction": "string"
      }
    ],
    "pageSize": 0,
    "currentPage": 0
  }
```

to:

http://host/api/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][field]=myfield&searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][value]=myvalue&searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][conditionType]=eq&..

Some suggestions ?
A.

Comment: why don't you pass your json string as payload to api? That would be better i guess.

Comment: Question is: How your server is expecting the URL to looks like?
You cane send it as you wrote, but if your server doesn't know what is mean, it' doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Thank U for answer, but ...
I've tryed to pass directly with payload json string and api give me an error, when I put instead query string like in my example, api respond in right way.
In PHP is very simple: json can be converted in array and so with function "http_build_query" it's done ! I'm suprised that not exist similar method .

Alb

Comment: I have an idea. I can made simple proxy url which convert json string using php to correct url than result catched by java I can pas to final api url. Not elegant way but method to resolve my problem.